# Single Inheritance of Controller Classes in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, inheritance, controller, laravel-5

Hi i am trying to do single inheritance in Laravel 5.2 for Controllers.

This is my parent basecontroller class

```
 <?php

 namespace App\Http\Controllers\Moviesfrontend;

 use Illuminate\Http\Request;

 use App\Http\Requests;
 use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;


 class BaseController extends Controller
 {
     public function __construct($request)
     {
         //code to check whether city is set in session or not
         $selectedcity=$request->session()->get('selectedcity');

     }
 }
```

In BaseController class construct will fetch the city name stored in session.
Now i want to access this city name stored in $selectedcity in my child class.

My child controller class is

```
  <?php

  namespace App\Http\Controllers\Moviesfrontend;

  use Illuminate\Http\Request;

  use App\Http\Requests;
  use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

  class HomeController extends BaseController
  {

      public function __construct(Request $request)
      {

          parent::__construct($request);

      }

      public function index(Request $request)
      {
          echo $selectedcity;
      }
  }
```

Bedefault I guess parent class variables are accessible to child class but this is not working and i am getting error message that $selectedcity not found.

Kindly assist me accessing this variable in chlid class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `$selectedcity` is a [local variable](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php). It only exists in the function scope of the constructor. It will be gone after the constructor is invoked. You need to assign it to an [instance variable](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php) instead, e.g.

```
class BaseController extends Controller
{
    protected $selectedCity;

    public function __construct($request)
    {
        $this->selectedCity = $request->session()->get('selectedcity');
        …
```

However, that would make it accessible to *any* subclass derived from the `BaseController`. If that's what you want, do it as shown.

But from the code you show, the `BaseController` looks superfluous to have. Just remove the `BaseController` and move the constructor to the `HomeController`:

```
class HomeController extends Controller
{
    private $selectedCity;

    public function __construct($request)
    {
        $this->selectedCity = $request->session()->get('selectedcity');
        …
```

To access the instance variable, you have to fetch it via `$this`, e.g.

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    echo $this->selectedCity;
    …
```

Make sure to read the [chapter on Object Inheritance in the PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.inheritance.php) if these topics are unclear to you.

Comment: I did same thing as you said still its showing me Undefined Variable : selectedcity  , and i have 4-5 controllers where i have written code to check whether session has got the value or not, so i was trying to create parent class in which i want to write the code to check session value is set or not so i created BaseController .

Comment: @dollar if you still get this error, you did something wrong. You are probably missing a `$this` somewhere. Or you did not create an instance property. In any case, this is inheritance 101. See this example as a proof of concept: http://codepad.org/Fm9Qu54h

Comment: gr8 thanks it worked, same way can i write functions in base class and access them in chlid class...?

Comment: @dollar yes, like I said: Make sure to read the chapter on Object Inheritance in the PHP Manual if these topics are unclear to you.